# Contenedor docker deja de funcionar con el tiempo

Tags: nodejs, api, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-server

Estoy realizando un api en nodejs, el caso es que esta api yo la convertí en un contenedor de docker y la publiqué en servidor de ubuntu en internet, el contenedor funciona correctamente por ciertas horas pero después deja de funcionar por alguna razón, sin embargo cuando me meto al servidor para ver que contenedores está corriendo, el contenedor de la api está subido funcionando "correctamente", quisiera saber si alguno sabe la razón de esto y cómo podría corregirlo. A continuación voy a adjuntarla configuración del Dockerfile de mi api.

```
FROM node:9-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Cuando digito el comando docker logs iddelcontenedor me saca lo siguiente:

```
{ Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
    at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:356:12)
    at Connection.write (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:230:32)
    at Connection.writePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:279:12)
    at Query.start (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/query.js:55:16)
    at Query.execute (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:39:22)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:425:32)
    at Connection.addCommand (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:447:12)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at router.get (/app/src/routes/task.routes.js:7:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) code: 'EPIPE', fatal: true }
{ Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at router.get (/app/src/routes/task.routes.js:7:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10) fatal: true }
{ Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at router.get (/app/src/routes/task.routes.js:7:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10) fatal: true }
{ Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at router.get (/app/src/routes/task.routes.js:7:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10) fatal: true }
{ Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at router.get (/app/src/routes/task.routes.js:7:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10) fatal: true }
{ Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at GetAllUsers.Promise (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:8:29)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at UserService.GetAllUsers (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:7:16)
    at GetUsers (/app/src/Controllers/user.controller.js:6:39)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) fatal: true }
(node:28) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at GetAllUsers.Promise (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:8:29)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at UserService.GetAllUsers (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:7:16)
    at GetUsers (/app/src/Controllers/user.controller.js:6:39)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
(node:28) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
(node:28) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
{ Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at GetAllUsers.Promise (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:8:29)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at UserService.GetAllUsers (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:7:16)
    at GetUsers (/app/src/Controllers/user.controller.js:6:39)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) fatal: true }
(node:28) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at GetAllUsers.Promise (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:8:29)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at UserService.GetAllUsers (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:7:16)
    at GetUsers (/app/src/Controllers/user.controller.js:6:39)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
(node:28) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 8)
{ Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at GetAllUsers.Promise (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:8:29)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at UserService.GetAllUsers (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:7:16)
    at GetUsers (/app/src/Controllers/user.controller.js:6:39)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) fatal: true }
(node:28) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at GetAllUsers.Promise (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:8:29)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at UserService.GetAllUsers (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:7:16)
    at GetUsers (/app/src/Controllers/user.controller.js:6:39)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
(node:28) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 12)
{ Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at GetAllUsers.Promise (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:8:29)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at UserService.GetAllUsers (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:7:16)
    at GetUsers (/app/src/Controllers/user.controller.js:6:39)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) fatal: true }
(node:28) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state
    at Connection._addCommandClosedState (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:137:17)
    at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:510:17)
    at GetAllUsers.Promise (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:8:29)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at UserService.GetAllUsers (/app/src/Services/user.service.js:7:16)
    at GetUsers (/app/src/Controllers/user.controller.js:6:39)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
(node:28) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 16)
```

Cabe aclarar que yo estoy manejando las promesas con async await y new promise, además de que no estoy cerrando las conexiones que hago a la base de datos por lo que en teoría no debería de sacar ese error. Estoy utilizando la dependencia de mysql2.
Este es el código de mis consultas

```
const {encrypt,decrypt}=require("../logic/EncryptDecrypt");
const mysqlConnection=require("../database");
const { promise } = require("../database");
const nodemailer=require("nodemailer");

    class UserService{
    
        async GetAllUsers(){
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM Usuario',(err,rows,fields)=>{
                    if(!err){
                        resolve(rows)
                    }else{
                        console.log(err);
                        reject(err);
                    }
                })
                mysqlConnection.end();
            })
        }
        async InsertUser(Cedula,Nombre,Apellido,Foto,Correo,Contra,Sede,Telefono){
            let u;
            const request=await this.GetUserbyCorreo(Correo).then(r=>{
                u=r
            }).catch(err=>{
                console.log(err);
            })
            if(JSON.stringify(u)==="[]"){
                return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                    const query=`
                        CALL InsertUserOrEdit(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
                    `;
                        let token=String((Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+54)))+"a%62#bc7def";
                        let password=encrypt(Contra);
                        let tokenEncrypt=encrypt(token);
                        this.SendEmail(Correo,tokenEncrypt.content);
                        mysqlConnection.query(query,[Cedula,Nombre,Apellido,Foto,Correo,password.content,Sede,Telefono,0,tokenEncrypt.content,0,0,password.iv],(err,rows,fields)=>{
                            if(!err){
                                resolve({Status:200,Message:"Usuario insertado correctamente"})
                            }else{
                                console.log(err);
                                reject({Status:400,Message:"Syntaxis inválida",Error:err})
                            }
                        })
                        mysqlConnection.end();
                })
            }else{
                return {Status:409,Message:"El usuario insertado ya existe en la base de datos"};
            }
        }
        async UpdateUser(Cedula,Nombre,Apellido,Foto,Correo,Contra,Sede,Telefono,TipoUsuario,tokenEncrypt,Permiso){
    
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                const query=`
                    CALL InsertUserOrEdit(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
                `;
                    let password=encrypt(Contra);
                    mysqlConnection.query(query,[Cedula,Nombre,Apellido,Foto,Correo,password.content,Sede,Telefono,TipoUsuario,tokenEncrypt.content,Permiso,1,password.iv],(err,rows,fields)=>{
                        if(!err){
                            resolve({Status:200,Message:"Usuario Actualizado correctamente"})
                        }else{
                            console.log(err);
                            reject({Status:400,Message:"Syntaxis inválida",Error:err})
                        }
                    })
                    mysqlConnection.end();
            })
          
        }
        async GetUserbyCorreo(Correo){
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Correo=?',[Correo],(err,rows,fields)=>{
                    if(!err){
                        resolve(rows);
                    }else{
                        console.log(err);
                        reject(err);
                    }
                })
                mysqlConnection.end();
            })
        }
        async Login(Correo, Contra){
            let u;
            let request=await this.GetUserbyCorreo(Correo).then(response=>{
                u=response;
            }).catch(err=>{
                console.log(err);
            })
            if(JSON.stringify(u)==="[]"){
                return {Status:404, Message:"Contraseña o correo incorrecto"}
            }else{
                let auxpass=decrypt({iv:u.Iv,content:u.Contra})
                if(auxpass===Contra){
                    return {Status:200, Message:"Sesión exitosa", Token:u.Token}
                }else{
                    return {Status:404, Message:"Contraseña o correo incorrecto"}
                }
            }
        }
        
        async GenerateToken(Correo){
            let token=String((Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+54)))+"a%62#bc7def";
            let tokenEncrypt=encrypt(token);
            let u;
            const request=await this.GetUserbyCorreo(Correo).then(r=>{
                u=r
            }).catch(err=>{
                console.log(err);
            })
            if(JSON.stringify(u)==="[]"){
                return {Status:404, Message:"No se pudo generar un token porque la cuenta no existe"}
            }else{
                let message;
                let request2=await this.UpdateUser(u.Cedula,u.Nombre,u.Apellido,u.Foto,u.Correo,u.Contra,u.Sede,u.Telefono,u.TipoUsuario,tokenEncrypt.content,u.Permiso).then(u=>{
                    message=u;
                }).catch(err=>{
                    console.log(err);
                })
                if(message.Status===200){
                    this.SendEmail(u.Email,tokenEncrypt.content);
                    return {Status:200,Message:"Token generado correctamente",Data:tokenEncrypt.content}
                }else{
                    return {Status:500,Message:"Ha ocurrido un error en el servidor"}
                }
            }
    
        }
        SendEmail(Email,token){
            var transporter=nodemailer.createTransport({
                service:'Gmail',
                auth:{
                    user:'myemail',
                    pass:'contraseña'
                }
            });
            var mailoptions={
                from:'email',
                to:Email,
                subject:'Confirmación de correo electrónico',
                text:`Este es tu token de seguridad ${token}`
            }
            transporter.sendMail(mailoptions,function(err,info){
                if (err){
                    return {Status:500, Message:"Ha ocurrido un error enviando el correo"}
                }else{
                    return {Status:200,Message:"Se ha enviado un token al correo ingresado"}
                }
            });
        }
    
    }
    module.exports=new UserService();
```

Y este el código de mi conección a la base de datos:

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
const mysqlConnection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'myip',
    port:'myport',
    user:'myuser',
    password:'mypassword',
    database:'REME',
})
mysqlConnection.connect(function (err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("DB is connected");
    }
})
module.exports=mysqlConnection
```

Comment: Falta información para poder determinar una causa. Puedes usar `docker logs nombre_contenedor` para ver los mensajes que la aplicación haya ido mostrando en el contenedor. Tal vez así encuentres mensajes de error que te den alguna pista.

Comment: Digité el comando para ver los mensajes, voy a editar la respuesta

Comment: Yo diría que ahora la pregunta ya no está relacionada con Docker. El programa se te "rompe" porque la base de datos cierra la conexión. Quizás un _timeout_, quizás otro error... No sé nada de programación con nodejs. Te sugiero que edites la pregunta para quitar las referencias a docker, y que la enfoques como una pregunta sobre nodejs y sql, especialmente en el título, para recibir más atención de quienes entiendan de esos temas.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, y tienes toda la razón, el problema no era el contenedor, este operaba correctamente, la raíz del problema estaba en que la conexión al servidor de base de datos cerraba inesperadamente, editaré mejor la pregunta y me responderé por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.

Comment: Hola @AlvaroGarzón al final cuál fue la solución, tengo el mismo tema!